# Disable ASP:dropdownlist based on the selection of another ASP:Dropdownlist.value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two asp.net dropdownlists that I want to manipulate clientside with Javascript. 
These two dropdowns are inside a modal open: function()

When dropdown1.value == "me" 
I want dropdown2.value to be disabled

How can I accomplish this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    if (document.getElementById('<%=dropdown1.ClientID%>').value == 'Me')
                        document.getElementById('<%=dropdown2.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
                    });
```

(optional) Part 2 I need to set an entity framework value to null after dropdown2 has been disabled how could I accomplish this without a postback?

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, use it. Mixing your syntax just makes life difficult. Also, stick to asking 1 question per post. You're more likely to get it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
   if($("#<%=dropdown1.ClientID%>").val() == "Me")
      $("#<%=dropdown2.ClientID%>").prop("disabled",true);
});
```

Part 2 :

You would need to make an ajax call to a code behind or webservice to do that.

**.ASPX**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "PageName.aspx/CodeBehindMethodName",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

            success: function (result) {


            },
            error: function (error) {

            }
             });
```

**.ASPX.CS**

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static void Test()
        {
          // Call EF code
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input I now have somewhere to go from your part 2. 

Part 1 still is not working unfortunately.

Comment: do you get any error ? Have you checked if the 1st dropdown has a value equals "Me" and not "ME" ?